# Spring boot Thin Jar gradle plugin is not working with gradle 7.1

Tags: java, gradle, java-8, jar, gradle-plugin

### Problem

I could not execute the thin Jar plugin.
when I execute the following command `./gradlew thinJar` I got the following error.

### Error In Terminal

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':thinPom' (type 'PomTask').
  - In plugin 'org.springframework.boot.experimental.thin-launcher' type 'org.springframework.boot.experimental.gradle.PomTask' field 'output' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @OutputFile.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'output'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'output'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
```

### My Setup

my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'idea'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'application'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.8'
    id 'org.liquibase.gradle' version '2.0.3'
    id "org.springframework.boot.experimental.thin-launcher" version "1.0.27.RELEASE"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    // Other Dependencies
}
```

My Project Gradle Versions are listed below

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-06-14 14:47:26 UTC
Revision:     989ccc9952b140ee6ab88870e8a12f1b2998369e

Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_292 (Private Build 25.292-b10)
OS:           Linux 4.15.0-151-generic amd64
```

Comment: this looks like a breaking change that was introduced in gradle 7. You might need to open a defect against that plugin - or event better, provide a fix. In the meantime, downgrading gradle to anything lower than 7, should fix it.

Comment: I tried updating my Gradle to 7.3 and same issue. There is a ticket in the [spring-boot-thin-launcher Github](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-boot-thin-launcher/issues/174)